# Haxe 4: Uncaught exception macro-in-macro

Tags: haxe

I had code like this working with Haxe 3:

```
macro public static function get(key:String)
{
    return Context.makeExpr(Context.definedValue(key), Context.currentPos());
}
```

However, after migrating to Haxe 4 this fails to compile with error:

> Uncaught exception macro-in-macro

How should I go about migrating this function to Haxe 4? Is there a better way to access build flags in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: That function on its own seems to compile just fine for me... Are you trying to use it from _within_ a macro? In that case you can just use `Context.definedValue()` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up removing this whole `get` method and switching occurrences to use [Compiler.getDefine()](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#getDefine) instead, which is supported both by Haxe 3 and 4.

I believe the problem we were facing was related with the fact that this static macro `get` was being called from our test runner script, so that probably was the place where a macro was calling another macro. Still, I tried to put the solution suggested by Jeff Ward in place but kept getting the same result.

Answer (score 3):

As @Gama11 alluded to, there's not actually a problem with your macro function, there's a problem with where you're calling it from. (Haxe 4 may have gotten more strict with these checks.)

If you have:

**Main.hx**

```
class Main
{
  public static function main()
  {
    // Can call get from here:
    var cvar = MacroUtil.get('cvar');
    MacroUtil.some_macro_function();
    trace('Hello world! cvar=${ cvar }');
  }
}
```

**MacroUtil.hx**

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class MacroUtil
{
  macro public static function get(key:String):Expr
  {
    return Context.makeExpr(Context.definedValue(key), Context.currentPos());
  }

  macro public static function some_macro_function()
  {
    // Cannot call get from here:
    var cvar:Expr = get('cvar');

    trace('will trace at compile time, and cvar is ${ cvar }');
    return macro trace('will trace at runtime');
  }
}
```

And execute it with: `haxe -x Main -D cvar=abc`

That will generate the error you're experiencing. It's because in `some_macro_function`, you're already in the macro context, so you can't call the macro function `get` from there.

There are a couple ways of dealing with this.

### One Approach

You can use `#if macro` / `if !macro` to detect the macro context and adjust accordingly. So as silly as this looks, it does indeed solve your particular problem:

```
class MacroUtil
{
  #if !macro macro #end public static function get(key:String):Expr
  {
```

This function signature says, if I'm already in the macro context, don't consider this function a macro function. It's just a static helper at that point. And remember that it returns an `Expr`, not a String like it does in the main context.

If you mix macro and non-macro functions in a single file, you may also find yourself needing to use `#if macro` to avoid this condition as well.

### Another Approach

You can refactor your macro functions into macro functions and macro helpers. It's a little more verbose, but maybe a little more clear as to what's happening:

**MacroUtil.hx**

```
import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;

class MacroUtil
{
  macro public static function get(key:String):Expr
  {
    return Context.makeExpr(MacroHelpers.get_define(key), Context.currentPos());
  }

  macro public static function some_macro_function()
  {
    // Cannot call get from here:
    var cvar:String = MacroHelpers.get_define('cvar');

    trace('will trace at compile time, and cvar is ${ cvar }');
    return macro trace('will trace at runtime');
  }
}

class MacroHelpers
{
  public static function get_define(key:String):String
  {
    return Context.definedValue(key);
  }
}
```

If you do it this way, then your macro functions all call the MacroHelpers, and non-macro function call the MacroUtils. Notice the helper returns a String, and it's up to the call-site to then convert it to an expression, if that's what they want.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation, I could understand the issue better after reading it! However, even when I do the fixes proposed here I can't get it to work, it still produces the same error of macro-in-macro. I tried to find where in my code there was another macro calling this function `get()` but I could not find it.

Comment: Hmm... it'd be hard to debug without looking through the code. One random idea -- `get()` is a rather generic function name, hard to track, and maybe called inadvertently? Perhaps try renaming the function? VSCode's Haxe plugin may help find all references?